# Trying to work out my average running speed on garmin in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I want to plot how my average running pace has changed over time from data downloaded from my Garmin.

I've tried a few things:

- Dividing distance by time (I get this error `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'float' and 'str'`).
- Just using the pace as given, but this seems to be in a strange format as the `max()` and `min()` functions don't give the fastest and slowest items.

I'm guessing it's going to be easiest to divide distance by time somehow, but I can't work out how to get them both in the right format.

`df_cleaner['speed'] = df_cleaner['distance']/df_cleaner['time']`

I'm hoping to get the KPH, but instead I get this error:

`TypeError: Cannot divide float64 data by TimedeltaArray`

Comment: `df_cleaner['distance']/df_cleaner['time'].dt.total_seconds`?